# Twilio Elastic SIP Trunking Call Custom SIP Headers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In Twilio Rest API for each call there is a response which uniquely identify calls

> **Twilio-Request-Id**: RQ5cedae4e7e7e4e70937a8198f5d2d1c0
>
> **Twilio-Request-Duration**: 0.103

I want use Twilio Elastic SIP Trunking Call. So messages will be in raw SIP formats.

**I wonder if Twilio provides this unique response Id-s**(which you can use to identify your call details uniquely by) **as custom SIP Headers extensions** such as

> **X**-Twilio-Request-Id = ...
>
> **X**-Twilio-Request-Duration = ...

And **what other custom SIP extension headers provided by Twilio** about calls which are done via Elastic SIP Trunking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Twilio send a unique Id in SIP OK Response

> **X-Twilio-CallSid**: CA70554....